# woocommerce: removing link on get_categories and get_tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce outputting get_categories and get_tags in the example below, but need them to be text only. At present, it outputs text with a link to the category / tag. Can the link component be removed?

```
<?php echo $child_product['product']->get_categories(); ?>
<?php echo $child_product['product']->get_tags(); ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else was looking for a solution to this...

```
<?php echo strip_tags ($child_product['product']->get_categories()); ?>
```